# How to append row data to table one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html code

```
    <tr id="tHead">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
            for(i=0;i<obj.data.length;i++){
                $("#tHead").after("<tr>" +
                 "<td>" + obj.data[i].name1 +
                 "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name2 + 
                 "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name3 + 
                 "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name4 + 
                 "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name5 + 
                 "</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now I can append data after "tHead" tr.
Because I use .after in my js code, so the data row will append one by one after"tHead" which will make my first data row become the last one in table.

I need first data row will be first row on table when I append it. 
What can I do to make it correct?

I try to use .append but not work, the new row will directly append in the end of "tHead" row.

Comment: Use reverse loop, `for (i = obj.data.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {`

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use `.append()` on the parent table, instead of using `.after()` on the `#tHead`

```
success: function(obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
        $("#tHead").parent("table").append("<tr>" +
         "<td>" + obj.data[i].name1 +
         "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name2 + 
         "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name3 + 
         "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name4 + 
         "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name5 + 
         "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

your rows will now be appended in chronological order.

A second solution would be to use `.after()` on the `:last` psuedo selector together with the `.siblings()` selector used with `#tHead`.

```
success: function(obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
        $("#tHead").siblings("tr:last").after("<tr>" +
         "<td>" + obj.data[i].name1 +
         "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name2 + 
         "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name3 + 
         "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name4 + 
         "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name5 + 
         "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Invert your loop , and it will work as you want

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
       url: "data.json",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(obj) 
       {
           for(i=obj.data.length-1;i>=0;i--)
           {
              $("#tHead").after("<tr>" +
               "<td>" + obj.data[i].name1 +
               "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name2 + 
               "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name3 + 
               "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name4 + 
               "</td><td>" + obj.data[i].name5 + 
               "</td></tr>");
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Add some description, or remove this answer and add this as comment

Comment: you can write the same in comment also. @Diptox

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal Just because an answer is short enough to be a comment, it doesn't mean that it is not an answer. This is an answer to the question, LQ, but is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this maybe:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
     url: "data.json",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(obj) {

     $("#tHead").append("<tr>");//----------- open new row.
     obj.forEach(function(row) {
         $("#tHead").append("<td>");
         $("#tHead").append(row);//---------- actual info.  
         $("#tHead").append("</td>");
     });
     $("#tHead").append("</tr>");//---------- close new row.
   }
  }
 });    
});
```

An excellent read can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/2645091 
on the different ways to iterate arrays.

Comment: This does not answer the problem. OP's problem is the order rows appear in his table. He don't want them to appear directly under `#tHead` but after the last  `tr`.

Comment: @NachoDawg I disagree with you on that. If you refer to this line "I need first data row will be first row on table when I append it. What can I do to make it correct?" clearly shows what he is asking. I think you were thinking that his code example was his question.